# Coding solution to code step by step algorithm-solver

Tags: python, algorithm, math

This is a rather general question: There is [this](http://matrixcalc.org/en/) webpage which lets you calculate Eigenvalues, Eigenspaces, etc... It also gives you step-by-step solutions. Is there any coding language or module (preferably in Python) which makes it easier to code something like this, or must this be coded manually?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The module `numpy` in Python provides a simple way (`numpy.linalg.eig()`) to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors without any effort. Do you really need to implement it by yourself? (homework?).

Comment: I did not try it but you may want to take a look at Sympy https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html. It lets you handle symbolic mathematics through code.

Comment: @Damien No homework, I am a math student and your professor said that it helps to really understand the algorithms. I also think it is just a fun challenge.

Comment: As mentioned, Sympy can probably find symbolic solutions for eigenvalue problems. But note that Sympy and symbolic computation systems in general can't give step by step solutions, because they rely on algorithms which are not easily broken down into recognizable steps. If you are specifically interested in step by step solutions, you might try searching for that term.